# Position breaks when browser resized

Tags: css

I'm having a box saying "Brand New Slide" which I positioned to a specific position using css code like: `left: -40px;` like the following image:

[image: OK when Browser full-screen]

But when I'm resizing the browser, the position breaks, like the following image:

[image]

How to address this issue? So that even if I resize the browser the box position relatively adjusts itself?

Comment: How is it -40px? It looks more like 60 in the first image. Can you post a jsFiddle? Do you want the box to resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This div asjusts itself when the browser resizes:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/fg9kL/